# Largest floating point variable

Tags: c++, double, floating-accuracy, buffer-overflow

The program takes for parameter one double and its doing computation with long float point values. eg `double myvar= n*0.000005478554 /298477`.
The problem is that im not sure that the real computational value is inserted to myvar.
because whenvever i change n it produce the same thing `cout<<"myvar ="<<myvar;`
What is the biggest type in c++ that can be used for maximum accuracy? Does a buffer overflow caused by this code because double variable cant hold too much info ? If yes what can happen and how can i detect it for later use?

Comment: The "biggest" floating-point type in C or C++ is `long double`. If you want more precision than that you have to use an external library such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: If you're working in C++, then you can design a Rational-Number class, which maintains {numerator,denominator}, and performs all the arithmetic operations on them. So it essentially gives you "infinite" precision, until you print it (when you need to specify how many digits you want to print after the decimal point). Here is an example that you can follow (or use): http://planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=9735&lngWId=3

Comment: long double is the same as double? what is his max size? answer my other questions  please

Comment: Try this in your code: `printf("%u %u\n",sizeof(double),sizeof(long double));`

Comment: @barakmanos: That should be `"%zu %zu"`, since `sizeof()` evaluates to type `size_t`, not `unsigned int`. Nitpicking, I know... up until you stumble across some strange machine where those two differ in size.

Comment: @FinlayLifny: You might want to check out `<cfloat>` and `<limits>`, headers that answer most of your questions.

Comment: You should also look at [std::setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

Comment: @DevSolar: a strange machine such as a Win64 machine (not that MSVC supports `"%zu"` anyway - but MinGW might). Sometimes it's easiest to just cast the `sizeof` result to `(unsigned)`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I live in the relative luxury of not giving a damn about what MSVC supports. That compiler is a joke IMHO. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`double` will hold values **much** smaller (and bigger) than `0.000005478554 /298477`. Any problem that you have is almost certainly caused by a bug in your code. **Show it!**

Try to reduce your problem to a few lines. This kind of problems can be reproduced with something as small as

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  double myvar = 7 * 0.000005478554 /298477;
  std::cout << myvar;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by much smaller and bigger?

Comment: The smallest positive value is certainly less then 1E-37 (about a billion billion billion times smaller than your number). Often, the smallest possible value is less than 1E-300. And the biggest `double` value is bigger than 1E+37, probably bigger than 1E+300.

Comment: @FinlayLifny: It means "you are probably doing it wrong". Size is not an issue, only precision. 0.000005478554/298477 is roughly 1.8355029030712584219219571357257008077674326665036E-11 which obviously cannot be represented by a `double`, only approximated (even if those 50 digits were _all_ digits, which they aren't). The important question is: _What are you trying to do_? Usually, when people ask this kind of question about precision, they do not properly understand what floating point math is about.

Comment: If my variable is double and i try to make computation with long digit number. What will happen to those other digits who cant get into the buffer? what myvariable will represent ? the number without those extra digits??

Comment: @FinlayLifny: You don't even need inputs with many digits. `1.0 / 3.0` won't fit either. The least significant digits are dropped.

Comment: so it get filled with what it can be filled from most to left significant bits?

Comment: @FinlayLifny: Yes. The exponent says where the first non-zero bit is, and the next 53 or so bits are stored (exact number depends on implementation, 53 is the common IEEE754 format)